# Formulating Table Relate using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, relates, arcgis-10.8

I'm moving our floorplans for a major organization into GIS to take advantage of analytical capabilities. I've prepared and figured polygons for each classification layer I want but when it comes to physical offices with personnel attached to them, I'm having trouble. Yes, I know there's ArcIndoors but my organization has an ArcMap Enterprise License so we're trying to see if we can get it done with version 10.8 without having to purchase anything else.

My problem lies in that office assignments are moved CONSTANTLY so I figured if I had data to be updated in an Excel employee "database," that I could just update that and a table relate would update the data in my project. Since people can have same names and names can change, I'm using employee ID numbers as the identifying factor with their names, titles, sectors, work status, etc as additional information attached to the ID number. However, we also want to be able to list vacancies attached to rooms which makes me think I should make the room number the relate. The room as associated info such as ownership, group office, square footage, and max occupancy. As there can be more than 1 person per room, I feel like having all this information in one table is messing me up.

How do you think this should be set and utilized?

I can't figure what to set as a relate and make this as seamless and efficient as possible.

Should I break these up into two tables: One for the room information and one for the employee information?

Then I can relate an employee ID number to a room associated with my polygons attributes and be able to show all information I want as a table join.

EDIT: I know we all look down at utilizing Excel as a "database" but I think it might be my best option as a quick way to update and manage the consistently changing data.

Comment: What does w/ and w/o mean? You are talking to an international community and using  abbreviations like that is unhelpful. Please edit you question and replace with English. You might also get a better response if you include some images of your data to explain your desired outcome?

Comment: When it comes down to it, you're asking for a database design.  Most database designers are not going to sign onto using Excel as a database. If you want to build a database, use a database technology (file geodatabase counts), not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Hornbydd w/ and w/o are well-known acronyms meaning 'with' and 'without' but I've edited it accordingly. I can't provide images of my data due to its secure nature but the column headings of what the data would be is noted.

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might not be able to relate to excel. I'd read up on the basics of relates: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-relating-tables.htm and even just do a quick test. I understand why you'd want to use excel (its quick and easy to update), but to me, even if it works, it sounds like a quick and dirty workflow which may cause future problems. If you want GIS capabilities, I'd seriously look at a real database as Vince suggests.

Comment: Do you have Enterprise or ArcGIS Online? You could put together a service that relates your offices to your people (table). In less than 4 hours you could bang out something that is accessible to anyone in your Org with a browser AND a really simple app to edit/update the table. It'd be almost as easy to update as excel, AND you could assign permissions to allow appropriate people to update it, instead of sharing an excel file across the network.

Comment: You can regularly move Excel-captured data to a file geodatabase table. Relates, joins, selects, and even sorts do not work well with foreign formats (those without an ArcMap primary key field), A file geodatabase table will have such a field.

Comment: And, even if you were not in a secure environment, I would be bothered by keeping that much information on employees in one place. Security needs to be part of the design plan.

Comment: @KHibma I completely forgot about creating a table in the DB. It's been 4 years since I've used GIS. And I agree with Danak that the security needs to be part of the plan. We have Enterprise and I already have the file GDB created with most of the feature classes sett with the exception of this "office" class. My main issue is how to break this office class down so that I can update the table and it automatically updates the field attributes. Would I be able to make this work best with my remarks at the end of the initial post?